# Run command on startup / login (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, boot

I was wondering which file I should place this bash command in so it will be run on startup.

```
# Start the MongoDB server
/Applications/MongoDB/bin/mongod --dbpath /usr/local/mongo/data --fork --logpath /usr/local/mongo/log
```

I have been scouring the net and think it is between `~/.bashrc`, `~/profile`, `/etc/bashrc`, `/etc/profile` or `~/.bash_profile`. Although I have tried these and they seem to run on *terminal startup* **not** *Mac startup*. Am I missing a file?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Officially none of these. The Apple suggested way is to use [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html). Guis to set this up include [lingon](https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) and [Launch Control](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/)

As for the files you mention the ones in the home directory ~/.bashrc, ~/profile, ~/.bash_profile  are only started when you login via a terminal. The ones in /etc are run by the shell starting for all users before the ones in home directory but only when a user login is made.. [bash manual](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_63.html)

The Unix startup script involved /etc/rc* but for OSX just use the launchd stuff

Comment: So if my command is inserted in either of the files in `/etc` it should be run on bootup? Does it matter what one it is in?

Comment: `/etc/bashrc` and so on are run when you start a shell, just like `~/.bashrc` - it's just that the former will be run whenever *any* user starts a shell, rather than just your user.

Comment: @Scott is correct I have corrected my answer

Comment: Okay, but I just can't work out how to use launchd, I tried making a plist file for my program but I have no idea how to run it or how to get it to run on boot.

Comment: @Mark link to "launchd" is broken :(

Answer (score 104):

[Another simple solution from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445525/403616):
You can:

- Start Automator.app;
- Select "Application";
- Click "Show library" in the toolbar (if hidden);
- Add "Run shell script" (from the Actions/Utilities);
- Copy-and-paste your script into the window;
- Test it;
- Save it somewhere: a file called `your_name.app` will be created);
- Depending your MacOSX version:

  - *Old* versions: Go to System Preferences → Accounts → Login items, or
  - *Before Ventura* version: Go to System Preferences → Users and Groups → Login items (top right), or
  - *Ventura and after* version: Go to System Preferences → General → Login items;
- Add this newly-created app;

Log off, log back in, and you should be done. ;)

Comment: Tested and works and it does not require launchd cumbersome plist editing nor paid Lingon app.

Comment: It does, however, add about 1804k of boilerplate to your three line shellscript!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions on making something useful with Automator. This will help me not just with the one task. Thank you kindly Jaime. I'm using it to turn off Turbo Boost via Turbo Boost Switcher. I own the pay version but the licensing mechanics are awful enough I prefer to use the free version which requires launch via terminal to avoid requests for admin password on every wake from sleep.

Comment: @android.weasel See Geekarist's answer http://superuser.com/a/995564/255375

Comment: Superuse-ful :-D, +1

Comment: suuuuuper cool thx

Comment: Confirmed working on OSX Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: This only runs at user login, not at machine startup.

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks
Tested on Monterey 12.1

Comment: You can also wrap a shell script as an app with Platypus. https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus

Answer (score 80):

To run a command on start up on OS X, you need to use `launchd`.

If you don't want to use [Lingon](http://lingon.sourceforge.net/), you need to create a `launchd` Property List. This is an XML file, so you can do it with your favourite text editor or alternatively you can use the Property List Editor that's installed with the Mac OS X Dev Tools. Create the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>some.meaningful.name</string> <!-- org.mongodb.mongodb perhaps? -->

    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>

    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>anAppropriateUser</string>

    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>anAppropriateGroup</string>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
            <string>/Applications/MongoDB/bin/mongod</string>
            <string>--dbpath</string>
            <string>/usr/local/mongo/data</string>
            <string>--fork</string>
            <string>--logpath</string>
            <string>/usr/local/mongo/log</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Save this in `/Library/LaunchAgents/some.meaningful.name.plist` (you will need an administrator account and/or `sudo`), then open a terminal and do:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/some.meaningful.name.plist
```

This will cause launchd to load the item which will cause it to start MongoDB on boot. As a bonus, `launchd` will monitor it and, if it exits for any reason, it will be re-started. To get rid of the item simply replace load in the above command with unload.

Comment: This page (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/launchd.plist) lists a lot of things something launched by launchd should not do.  If I want to run an arbitrary command at startup I may not have control of and the command may wind up doing those things.  In addition, I may not want launchd to restart and item that stops because it's a one-off or handles re-launching on its own.  What should I do in these cases?

Comment: @Scott, thank you. This is the most helpful answer I found on the internet.

Comment: This will attempt to run the application every 10 seconds, which works well for services that don't die. If this is for a script that runs once punctually (in my case, messaging once Slack on reboot) add `<key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key><true/>` to the dict.

Comment: Great point Mr Sanford. launchd which doesn't give up creates huge log files which then slow your Mac (due to reading and writing such large log files continually). I may use that fix on some of the badly written commercial software running on my computer now.

Comment: Note to self: If you need environment variables: https://serverfault.com/questions/111391/use-an-environment-variable-in-a-launchd-script

Comment: Should I expect `launchctl load` to load directly or should I logout/login? (or maybe just  kill the WindowServer?)

Answer (score 52):

To launch commands when logging in, you can do this:

- Create a text file containing your commands (bash script):

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  # Start the MongoDB server
  /Applications/MongoDB/bin/mongod --dbpath /usr/local/mongo/data --fork --logpath /usr/local/mongo/log
  ```
- Save this file in `~/Library/Startup.cmd`
- You can test it by double-clicking the file in the Finder
- Make it executable: `chmod +x ~/Library/Startup.cmd`
- Add this file in System Preferences > Accounts > Login items

Comment: best and easiest answer imho. much easier than accepted solution. note that it's in System Preferences > Users & Groups >  Login items ... (not Accounts)... and also note that the file can be anywhere, doesn't have to end with .cmd either. just chmod +x it.

Comment: However, login items run at login, not at system startup. If you run a server, that's a big difference.

Comment: You're right @not2savvy. For a server I would recommend @Sridhar-Sarnobat's answer with `@reboot`.

However my answer would allow to start a graphical program, that's why I think it's useful.

Comment: Why ends with `cmd` instead of `sh`?

Comment: Whether your Library script path ends in cmd or sh, this won't necessarily actually _execute_ the script, when invoked in this fashion. In my case (macOS 10.15.4 Catalina), it opens it in XCode (sh) or Visual Studio Code (cmd) instead, which obviously isn't useful.

Comment: @Simin Jie because I thought it would guarantee that the system would execute the script instead of opening it in an editor. But as ecmanaut writes this is not the case.

Comment: This only works when you have associated `cmd` or `sh` with the Terminal app in macOS! In my cas my script ended with `.sh` and that extension was associated with Xcode. On every login, the file was opened in Xcode instead of being executed. After changing the application association in Finder, it worked fine.

Comment: I didn't get the option to associate the file with Terminal - that was greyed out. But using a `.command` extension did the trick for me (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580918/open-a-shell-script-in-terminal-mac-no-matter-what-the-default-application-for)

Comment: Would rather go for launchd solution as "Other mechanisms (than launchd) for starting daemons and agents are subject to removal at Apple’s discretion." https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/script-management-with-launchd-apdc6c1077b-5d5d-4d35-9c19-60f2397b2369/mac

Answer (score 14):

If you want an approach that will work on Linux & Mac OS X, a cron task should should be sufficient (edit your cron tasks by executing `crontab -e`):

```
@reboot /path/to/script
```

(credits: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49207/how-do-i-set-a-script-that-it-will-run-on-start-up-in-freebsd)

Comment: This is really cool!  Means a simple way to run scripts on startup (that Apple haven't messed with).  Thanks!

Comment: Enjoy it while it lasts. Apple have deprecated crontab :( hopefully Homebrew will have a community edition that works the same way

Comment: Oh dear - they (Apple) just seem to chip away at the Unix-ness of their Unix based OS.....  Thanks for the heads-up though

Answer (score 3):

You will have to look at how `launchd` and `launchctl` work on MacOS. You could start by reading the man pages for both the commands. You could then look inside `/Library/LaunchAgents/` and `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` for examples of how to set up applications to load at different times through the `launchctl` interface.

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652351/creating-a-timed-launchd-plist) I found on Stack Overflow that might help you further.

Answer (score 1):

Although I do not find the answers that are asking you to add the call in .bash_profile or .bashrc acceptable, they *could* work imho.

You *could* right click on your Terminal Icon when on Dock, Select Options > Open at login.

I have an auto-login VPN script for work. I need to open Terminal too when working. So I prefer it automatically launches at startup and I used .bashrc to run my vpn script automatically.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.

Comment: There is one answer suggesting that, which has -4 votes; for good reasons: when placed in .bashrc or .bash_profile the service would start every time you open a terminal window or login elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in a very simple unix answer to this problem and found it at another [site](https://coderwall.com/p/u003pa/bash-startup-scripts-on-linux-and-mac-os-x).  Here is a summary of the solution.

The standard for login shells is to always look for the bash configuration files with "profile" in the name, in this order: /etc/profile, ~/.bash_profile, then ~/.bash_login and lastly ~/.profile. When login shells exit, they read ~/.bash_logout.

In my case I just created the ~/.bash_profile and then I opened the preferences for the Mac Terminal app and changed the "Shell opens with" option from default to /bin/bash.  That's it.  Clean and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could use crontab:

First, create a script somewhere (let's say /path/to/script.sh) and type the command you wanted to run there. Then type `chmod +x /path/to/script.sh`.

Now, in the Terminal:

```bsh
EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

You will be presented with a text editor in the terminal.

Type in the file:

```
@reboot /path/to/script.sh
```

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, hit <kbd>y</kbd>, and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, and on the next boot, this will run!

If you wanted to run a command in the background, simply add an & after the command in the script.

Answer (score 0):

This answer explains how to run a command on at login and is based on [Geekarist's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/229773/run-command-on-startup-login-mac-os-x/995564#995564). Here, the script is wrapped in an AppleScript application. AppleScript was chosen over a workflow, because the Script Editor application does not overwrite manual changes made to an applications `Info.plist` file, where as the Automator application does. Wrapping the script in an application also allows the user to customize privacy settings. If the script exits with a non-zero status, then the application shows a popup window with an error message. Otherwise, no other windows are shown.

Steps are given below.

1. Use the Script Editor application to create a application containing the line given below.

   ```
   do shell script quoted form of (POSIX path of (path to me) & "Contents/Resources/Startup.sh")
   ```
2. Save the application to your `~/Applications` folder. (If this folder does not exist, then create the folder.) Here, I will name the application "My Agent". You may choose a different name.
3. Create a file named `Startup.sh` in My Agent application's `Contents/Resources` folder. Place the script in the file. A copy of the script from [Geekarist's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/229773/run-command-on-startup-login-mac-os-x/995564#995564) is given below.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   # Start the MongoDB server
   /Applications/MongoDB/bin/mongod --dbpath /usr/local/mongo/data --fork --logpath /usr/local/mongo/log
   ```
4. Enter the command given below to make `Startup.sh` executable.

   ```
   chmod +x ~/Applications/My\ Agent.app/Contents/Resources/Startup.sh
   ```
5. Make the My Agent application an agent. This will prevent (amongst other things) the My Agent application from appearing on the dock while executing at startup.

   ```
   /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :LSUIElement bool true" ~/Applications/My\ Agent.app/Contents/Info.plist
   ```

   The above command adds the following lines to My Agent application's `Info.plist` file.

   ```
       <key>LSUIElement</key>
       <true/>
   ```
6. Open the My Agent application in the Script Editor application. Compile the script, save and quit. This is necessary, because the `Info.plist` file was manually changed in the previous step.
7. Add the My Agent application to the user login items.

Answer (score -1):

Open Terminal app select Terminal preferences go to profiles
select Profiles
Under Startup enter source  path to script script Name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

open terminal, type

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

then add this text to the file:

```
/Applications/MongoDB/bin/mongod --dbpath /usr/local/mongo/data --fork logpath /usr/local/mongo/log
```

Comment: This would assume you open a Terminal window after logging in.