# How do I get an application to start on Mac OS X before anyone logs in?

Tags: osx-lion

I'm trying to get a Perforce server (p4d) to start when the Mac starts, but before anyone logs in. Specifically it's a Mac Mini running OS X 10.7.5. I have admin access, so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use `launchd` and add a `LaunchAgent`.

[SU Post with Good Tutorial](https://superuser.com/a/229792/121101)

There is also a GUI that can assist you with launchd called [Lingon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/).

`launchd` [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html)