# routing with 1 router/firewall and 2 modems

Tags: networking, router, routing, firewall

I've a firewall with 2 interfaces:
Interface1: LAN with some computers connected (Mac, Win, Linux)
Interface2: WAN with 2 modems connected

Now every computer has the gateway set to Firewall and Firewall gateway set to modem1.

I would like to let a computer (let's say Linux) use exclusively modem2.

Computers shares printers and other local devices, so they have to stay in the same LAN, so I cannot connect the computer to modem2 directly.

Route command on firewall is not useful because it does not choose based on source, only destination.

Route on computer seems not working, probably because the gateway is behind the firewall.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make and model of the firewall? what is it running?

Answer (score 1):

Standard ip routing is only based on destination, but there are alternatives, usually called "policy based routing".
I guess the key to doing what you want is in the firewall, which has the needed data to perform routing based on the client. 
How to do that depends on the software that is in that firewall though.
For a couple of alternatives in linux and macos you could see [Application / interface specific routing](https://superuser.com/questions/1303437/application-interface-specific-routing/1303520#1303520)

Comment: Good suggestion.
The Firewall is a standard Netgear, unfortunately without the option to change the firmware.
If I have to change the firewall with a Linux based computer, well, that could be a problem, for me. :-\

Comment: It might be doable. Take a look here: https://community.netgear.com/t5/Managed-Switches/PBR-Policy-Based-Routing-using-Managed-Switch/td-p/1138508