# Run command on startup (Mac), don't understand much

Tags: bash, mac, permissions, daemon

So [I'm trying to replicate this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/229773/run-command-on-startup-login-mac-os-x?newreg=6316f69947a24fc491740d983ee786de) but I am lost.

I tried creating a launch agent or daemon but neither of them work and I get this error in terminal with this command:

```
Vances-MacBook-Air:~ vancesmac$ sudo launchctl load/Library/LaunchAgents/mute.mac.at.startup.plist
```

Password:
/Library/LaunchAgents/mute.mac.at.startup.plist: Path had bad ownership/permissions

Here is what I have in that file; `<string>mute.mac.at.startup</string>`: This is what my plist file is called:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>mute.mac.at.startup</string>    

    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>

    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>anAppropriateUser</string>

    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>anAppropriateGroup</string>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
            <string>/Applications/FirstScript.txt</string>

    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I'm positive I'm doing something wrong here. I named the file "FirstScript.txt" because i was figuring out how to make those. I just have it in my applications folder for the time being. I'm trying to run this command on startup:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume=%80
```

So what is it that I'm not understanding? I tried using Automator for something like this but because it requires my password I can't do it. Plus I don't get the permissions thing because I have it intentionally set for everyone to read and write at the moment.