# CUPS not starting on start up on Mac OSX 10.15.3

Tags: mac, printing, cups

My Mac has suddenly stopped starting the CUPS service on startup. I can start CUPS by running

```
sudo /usr/sbin/cupsd
```

but when I restart my computer it requires me to run this command again.

Is there some simple reason that could be behind this? It never needed to be started manually before

Otherwise, how do I run this command automatically on start up?

Comment: Your command works, and running it on start up may work, but you should look into Services: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55214/whats-the-services-running-processes-manager-in-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to launch a program / service on boot.
The recommended way is via [launchd](https://www.launchd.info/).

I am not certain what is your current status, but generally speaking, you have to find (it may already be present in your system, as you had it loading on boot before), or create a Property List, say, as `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.cups.cupsd.plist`.
Then,

```
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.cups.cupsd.plist
```

To create it, you can use a GUI (e.g., [lingon](http://lingon.sourceforge.net/), or [LaunchControl](https://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/)),
or the built-in Property List Editor.

I am providing here a few useful links.

- [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/229792/245595), and others in the same question.
- http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110117121647762
- https://books.google.com/books?id=o9K8KEQic5sC&pg=PA458&lpg=PA458&dq=macos+cups+launchd
- https://opensource.apple.com/source/cups/cups-69/doc/sam.html

Links relating to disabling CUPS, which may be instructive:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2078738
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/331365/best-way-to-turn-off-cupsd