# How to locate unknown background applications ex. "Vitality ApS" in MacOS Ventura 13.1?

Tags: background, macos-ventura

I just got the notification about an "Vitality ApS" being an login item allowed in the background.
It shows in the control panel and I can disable it, but "How can I find the related application?"

[image]

Since I cannot find anything about this app via search engines, I tried to find the related application bundle on the M2 Apple.

Articles like [Run command on startup / login (Mac OS X)](https://superuser.com/questions/229773/run-command-on-startup-login-mac-os-x) point to seemingly empty (or now unused) folders.

I tried the following with no result:

```
launchctl list | grep -I  vitality

find    ~/Library/Launch* /Library/Launch* -iname '*vitality*'


find    ~/Library/Launch* /Library/Launch* -iname '*.plist' | while read F ; do
plutil -p "$F"
done | grep -I vitality
```

Without results.

What other options are there to find/locate the unknown app?

What is this "Vitality ApS"?

Comment: Precisely which OS version? 13.0.1 was notorious for presenting the developer's name in the security permissions rather than the app name. I've heard things have improved since, but might not still be fully fixed. Google says it's a software company in Denmark. Apps: GlimmerBlocker & Jabhts [none of which I've heard of, but I'm not Danish]

Comment: True,  **Ventura 13.1** (current as of Jan-'23)

Comment: And yes, thank you,  "GlimmerBlocker" is the background item that shows as "Vitality ApS"