# macOS - Running a plist script before boot up

Tags: mac, launchctl

The *left option* (alt key) of the MacBook is always pressed - not mechanically, but I guess it is generating the key press event. The on-screen keyboard shows the *option key* is pressed (has red border). Hence in the mac login screen (password screen), since the *option key* is pressed, the entered password characters become special characters (e.g., w become ∑).

Hence, I have disabled the *left option key* using `hidutil` as,

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x7000000E2,
    "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000000}]}'
```

I have made this into a plist script and loaded it using `launchctl`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.hidutilKeyMapping</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/hidutil</string>
        <string>property</string>
        <string>--matching</string>
        <string>{"ProductID":0x1234}</string> <!-- Replaced with actual product id -->
        <string>--set</string>
        <string>{"UserKeyMapping":[
            {
              "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc": 0x7000000E2,
              "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst": 0x700000000
            }
        ]}</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've loaded it as

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/local.hidutilKeyMapping.plist
```

Even though I have `RunAtLoad` set to *true*, it doesn't take effect until I've logged in.

I would like to have the key mapping applied (disable the *left option key*) during the boot time itself, i.e., during/before the apple logo appears.

I've tried placing the `plist` in

1. `~/Library/LaunchAgents`
2. `/Library/LaunchDaemons`

Both options don't seem to work i.e., key mapping is not applied until I get past the password screen.

How to invoke this plist script during boot time?

Note: I've temporarily reset the password to contain only special characters to enable entering the password.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/229792/8672) help?

Comment: @harrymc It is what I've done, but doesn't run before the password screen. But I kept the `plist` file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` and not `/Library/LaunchAgents`. Not sure if that would make a difference. Will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `LimitLoadToSessionType` to `StandardIO` worked for me.

```
<key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
<array>
<string>StandardIO</string>
</array>
```